# Login Page 'if' Display something in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript, if-statement

I'm kind of new in here. I'm creating a login page in HTML with JavaScript elements.

Basically, I have a login form. and if credentials are wrong I want it to show an alert in HTML which another JavaScript manages. Anyway I have setup a test page [here](http://webble.info/temp/login.html). As you can see, when you input has the wrong credentials, it will display an alert, but I want it to perform an action in HTML?

`<div class="notification error">` That is the code in HTML which will show that red box you see up the top & I will add text later.

Here's the Login form:

```
else {
$('.notification-detials')
}
return true;
}
// End -->
```

Maybe I've done something wrong there? But [here's](http://webble.info/temp/js/login.js) the code of the JS, which manages the notifications and other stuff.

BTW, when the notification is complete it would be cool for the code to be something like:

```
<div class="notification error">
<h1> Error </h1>
<p> You're details were entered incorrectly. Please try again <p> </div>
```

Comment: So you have a flash based app but you want to show a JS driven error message?

Comment: Nothing is flashed, sorry.. It's just a basic HTML form, but when the validation is shown as correct I want Java to apply an action from another Javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh shnitzal no! js validation of password and username are a majorly bad thing. I was able to go in and see the password and username.  Sorry but this is not something that should be done in javascript which is client side code.  Use PHP instead. :(

Comment: +1 or a system like Django which is easy to learn and will do auth+sessions for you.

Comment: It was just a test user name and password, I would apply some encryption in the future :) Would I be able to implement actions like that via PHP?

Comment: unfortunately I am not a PHP person, but on a very basic level, with PHP you send information to the server, that info is validated, and then it sends info back to the client (you can even send whole formatted blocks of HTML). But, again, I've never touched PHP in my life, so I only know the very basic concepts.

Comment: Ill try out Django! Thanks for all your help Joseph!

Comment: you're welcome :) and thanks to alex c for pointing out Django.  I hadn't actually heard of that till now.